# What causes standardised regression coefficients in a confirmatory factor analysis to be greater than one?

Tags: factor-analysis

I performed a CFA to reduce my items into factors.
However, due to the violations of non-normality, the results were really weird, and transformations didn't help. There were some standardozed regression coefficients that were negative and ones that were over 1 despite the factors itself having good Cronbach alphas.

1. Where could I have gone wrong in my CFA? What's the meaning behind getting path coefficients over 1?
2. Would it be suitable to even include such a bad-fit model into the write-up of my results?

Comment: Welcome to the site. The coefficients are called "standardized", not standard. Cronbach is a last name, and should be capitalized. If you have standardized coefficients greater than one, you probably also have variances below zero. The situation is referred to as "Heywood case" in factor analysis literature, so you might want to Google this phrase and see if something helps. Non-normality may or may not be a culprit. It would help if you demonstrated your results, including the non-normality diagnostics.

Comment: What's your sample size? How many factors and how many items per factor? Are factors correlated? What do you get when you run exploratory factor analysis with the same number of factors?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4081/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-a-heywood-case